# GWT and Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, gwt, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm currently working on a specification for a web application which consist of a administration interface, and a set of web-services which will be consumed by parter websites.

I been playing around with GWT and it seems like an amazing fit for the administration interface, but at the same time, I would love to use the Spring framework to produce the REST based web-service API exposed by the application.

My plan is to create two separate web applications, one for the admin and one for the web-services. One set up for spring and the other with the GWT app. Obviously, I wish to share the domain model between the two applications, I'm guessing this should be fairly trivial to accomplish? I'm thinking just to keep it simple, implement the full domain model in the GWT client project, and simply setting the sourcepath of the web-service to include the domain model from the relevant folders in the GWT project.

Now, to my question. I'm sure somebody out there have done something similar to this, are there any potential pitfalls I should be aware of before starting out?

I got a fair amount of time set aside for this project, but I never actually used GWT before for anything "serious" I just played around with it out of personal interest and I'm fairly experienced in both Swing and Android UI development, so I'm confident I can mange to use it for the (very simple) UI. The "unknown" in this equation is sharing of a domain model. I cant imagine this being a problem, since the domain model will be just POJO's (using JDBC, but again, I cant really imagine this being a problem).

Also, are there better ways of integrating GWT and Spring than simply doing to separate web applications and sharing their domain model?

Comment: if I am going to implement it, I would use the Google App Engine and GWT in one app. the REST can be exposed from GAE too. to do the pojo, you can also ues Spring Roo to speed up the development

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for your feedback, we wont deploy on Google App Engine though, it needs access to our oracle servers. It will be deployed on Tomcat initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to create two separate applications?
Create one, with a clearly separated application services tier. Expose this services via standard Spring annotations as webservices, and also expose access to this services via GWT requestfactory (unfortunately, as far as I know, currently requestfactory does not play nice with REST requests, mainly because their way of serialization). This approach results in only one entrance (facade) to your application and allows to use this facade in two different ways.

I've worked on several GWT+Spring projects - for standard cases development goes very fast, frameworks integrates very well. However, if you want to do some customization, e.g. introduce security based on spring security - you will need to do some hacks, such as overriding transport classes. Of course it takes some time, but results are very nice.

I would definitely recommend to take a look at Spring ROO sample applications (as far as I know, roo is partially developed by google guys).